# Is there a nvl() function in Ruby or do I have to write it myself?

Tags: ruby, oracle

I want to use an equivalent of Oracle's `nvl()` function in Ruby. Is there a built in function or do I have to write one myself?

Edit:

I am using it to rewrite some sql to ruby:

```
INSERT INTO my_table (id, val)
VALUES (1, nvl(my_variable,'DEFAULT'));
```

becomes

```
plsql.my_table.insert {:id => 1, :val => ???my_variable???}
```

Comment: Just for the sake of us non-Oracle users here: what does `nvl()` do? Well, that can be easily googled, so the more important question is: what do you *need* it to do?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You could use [Conditional assignment](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Ruby_Programming/Syntax/Operators)

```
x = find_something() #=>nil
x ||= "default"      #=>"default" : value of x will be replaced with "default", but only if x is nil or false
x ||= "other"        #=>"default" : value of x is not replaced if it already is other than nil or false
```

Operator `||=` is a shorthand form of the expression

```
x = x || "default"
```

Some tests

```
irb(main):001:0> x=nil
=> nil
irb(main):003:0* x||=1
=> 1
irb(main):006:0> x=false
=> false
irb(main):008:0> x||=1
=> 1
irb(main):011:0* x||=2
=> 1
irb(main):012:0> x
=> 1
```

And yes, If you don't want false to be match, you could use `if x.nil?` as Nick Lewis mentioned

```
irb(main):024:0> x=nil
=> nil
irb(main):026:0* x = 1 if x.nil?
=> 1
```

**Edit**:

```
plsql.my_table.insert {:id => 1, :val => ???????}
```

would be

```
plsql.my_table.insert {:id => 1, :val => x || 'DEFAULT' }
```

where x is the variable name to set in :val, 'DEFAULT' will be insert into db, when x is nil or false

If you only want nil to 'DEFAULT', then use following way

```
{:id => 1, :val => ('DEFAULT' if x.nil?) }
```

Comment: That doesn't work right if x is a non-nil false value, i.e. false.