# Is there built in support in rails for the default value substitution idiom?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I often write code to provide a default value upon encountering nil/empty value.

E.g:

```
category = order.category || "Any"
#  OR
category = order.category.empty? ? "Any" : order.category
```

I am about to extend the `try` method to handle this idiom.

```
category = order.try(:category, :on_nill => "Any")
#  OR
category = order.try(:category, :on_empty=> "Any")
```

I am wondering if Rails/Ruby has some method to handle this idiom?

**Note:**

I am trying to eliminate repetition of  `|| / or / ?` operator based idioms.

Essentially I am looking for a equivalent of `try` method for handling default substitution scenarios.

Without `try` method:

```
product_id = user.orders.first.product_id unless user.orders.first.nil?
```

With `try` method:

```
product_id = user.orders.first.try(:product_id)
```

It is easy to implement a generic approach to handle this idiom, but I want to make sure I do not reinvent the wheel.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4817266/if-string-is-empty-then-return-some-default-value).  ActiveSupport adds a [`presence`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_support_core_extensions.html#presence) method to all objects that returns its receiver if `present?` (the opposite of `blank?`), and `nil` otherwise.

Example:

```
host = config[:host].presence || 'localhost'
```

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps this might serve:

```
class Object
  def subst_if(condition, replacement)
    condition = send(condition) if condition.respond_to?(:to_sym)
    if condition
      replacement
    else  
      self
    end
  end
end
```

Used like so:

```
p ''.subst_if(:empty?, 'empty')       # => "empty"
p 'foo'.subst_if(:empty?, 'empty')    # => "foo"
```

It also takes stand-alone conditions, not related to the object:

```
p 'foo'.subst_if(false, 'bar')    # => 'foo'
p 'bar'.subst_if(true,  'bar')    # => 'bar'
```

I'm not crazy about the name `subst_if`.  I'd borrow whatever name Lisp uses for this function, if I knew it (assuming it exists).

Comment: +1, this is an interesting approach. I was thinking about extending the `try` method, as I am already using it in many places.

Answer (score 1):

Pretty sure its not baked in.  Here is a link to a [similar question/answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2817035/is-there-a-nvl-function-in-ruby-or-do-i-have-to-write-it-myself/2817082#2817082).  It is the approach that I take. Leveraging the ruby: `||=` syntax

**An aside:** This question also reminds me of the first Railscasts of all time: [Caching with instance variables](http://railscasts.com/episodes/1-caching-with-instance-variables) which is a useful screencast if you need to do this kind of operation in a Controller

Answer (score 0):

[fetch](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/Hash.html#method-i-fetch) will work in the case that you are looking for values by `index` values of an array or by `keys` in a hash ( or `ActionController::Parameters` aka `params` ). Otherwise, you will have to use the `||=` or `attempted_value || default_value` as described in the other answers.

The current accepted answer's example is rewritten here:

assuming:  `config = { my_host_ip: '0.0.0.0' }`

```
 config.fetch(:my_host_ip, 'localhost')
 # => "0.0.0.0" 

 config.fetch(:host, 'localhost')
 # => "localhost"
```

```
 a_thru_j = ('a'..'j').to_a
 # => ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j"]

 a_thru_j.fetch(1, 'not here')
 # => "b"

 a_thru_j.fetch(10, 'not here')
 # => "not here"
```

Note: without the default, you will raise an error when the `key`/`index` is not present:

```
 config.fetch(:host)
 # => KeyError: key not found: :host

 params.fetch(:host)
 # => ActionController::ParameterMissing: param is missing or the value is empty: host

 a_thru_j.fetch(10)
 # => index 10 outside of array bounds: -10...10
```