# If string is empty then return some default value

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Often I need to check if some value is blank and write that "No data present" like that:

```
@user.address.blank? ? "We don't know user's address" : @user.address
```

And when we have got about 20-30 fields that we need to process this way it becomes ugly.

What I've made is extended String class with `or` method

```
class String
  def or(what)
    self.strip.blank? ? what : self
  end
end

@user.address.or("We don't know user's address")
```

Now it is looking better. But it is still raw and rough

How it would be better to solve my problem. Maybe it would be better to extend `ActiveSupport class` or use helper method or mixins or anything else. What ruby idealogy, your experience and best practices can tell to me.

Answer (score 258, accepted):

ActiveSupport adds a [`presence`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_support_core_extensions.html#presence) method to all objects that returns its receiver if `present?` (the opposite of `blank?`), and `nil` otherwise.

Example:

```
host = config[:host].presence || 'localhost'
```

Comment: this is cool. Default rails posibilities are preffered. Thanx!

Comment: Firstly it is preffered because in my solution I should extend String, Fixnum and NilClass at least. And here I can just use clear code without bycles

Answer (score 12):

Phrogz sort of gave me the idea in PofMagicfingers comment, but what about overriding | instead?

```
class String
  def |(what)
    self.strip.blank? ? what : self
  end
end

@user.address | "We don't know user's address"
```

Answer (score 2):

Since you're doing this in Ruby on Rails, it looks like you're working with a model. *If* you wanted a reasonable default value *everywhere* in your app, you could (for example) override the `address` method for your `User` model.

I don't know ActiveRecord well enough to provide good code for this; in Sequel it would be something like:

```
class User < Sequel::Model
  def address        
    if (val=self[:address]).empty?
      "We don't know user's address"
    else
      val
    end
  end
end
```

...but for the example above this seems like you'd be mixing view logic into your model, which is not a good idea.

Comment: Yes, it is bad idea to set defaults in models :) My forms will weep

Answer (score 2):

Your **or** method might have some unwanted side-effects, since the alternative (default) value is always evaluated, even if the string is not empty.

For example

```
@user.address.or User.make_a_long_and_painful_SQL_query_here
```

would make extra work even if address is not empty. Maybe you could update that a bit (sorry about confusing one-liner, trying to keep it short):

```
class String
  def or what = ""
    self.strip.empty? ? block_given? ? yield : what : self
  end
end

@user.address.or "We don't know user's address"
@user.address.or { User.make_a_long_and_painful_SQL_query_here }
```

Comment: good remark. Got it. But why all code will be executed? look: `a=2 ; a == 2 ? "ok" : @b = 3 ; @b; #=> nil`

Comment: It will be executed when making the original call, not with the ternary operator. All the arguments will be evaluated on method call.

Answer (score 1):

It is probably better to extend ActiveRecord or individual models instead of String.

In your view, you might prefer a more explicit pattern like

```
@user.attr_or_default :address, "We don't know the user's address"
```

Comment: Is this part of Active Record? Did not find any references.

Answer (score 0):

Ruby:

```
unless my_str.empty? then my_str else 'default' end
```

RoR:

```
unless my_str.blank? then my_str else 'default' end
```

Answer (score 0):

I recommend to use options.fetch(:myOption, defaultValue) because it works great with boolean flags like the ones mentioned above and therefore seems better to use in general.

Examples

```
value = {}

puts !!(value.fetch(:condition, true)) # Print true
```

```
value = {}
value[:condition] = false

puts !!(value.fetch(:condition, true)) # Print false
```

```
value = {}
value[:condition] = true

puts !!(value.fetch(:condition, true)) # Print true
```

```
value = {}
value[:condition] = nil

puts !!(value.fetch(:condition, true)) # Print false
```