# `||` (`or`) clause with an `if` statement

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Is this not evaluating the `if` statement?

```
<%= current_user.profile.name || current_user.email if current_user.profile.name.blank? %>
```

Debug on `current_user.profile.name` shows it is an empty string, but it's not printing `email`. Changing to a ternary operator like this:

```
<%= current_user.profile.name.blank? ? current_user.email : current_user.profile.name %>
```

works, but I'd like to understand why the first way doesn't work.

Comment: `a || b if c` is parsed as `(a || b) if c` In this case, c is only true *if* the profile name is blank .. so, now, to the next part: suppose a is `""` (blank, must be given the `if`) and b is a fallback value, then consider: `"" || "hello world!"` *<- What is that result?* (Hint: What does ruby consider truthy values? What would the result of `nil || "hello world!"` be?)

Comment: so in ruby an empty string is not falsey... why would this still not work if i was checking for an empty string... while playing with this trying to figure it out, at one point I had `<%= current_user.profile.name || current_user.email if current_user.profile.name == '' %>` and it still wouldn't print the email

Comment: Exactly, `""` is not false-y :) In that case, what would `a` and `b` be? What would `a || b` be? Would it ever be useful? (Note that `str == ""` *implies* `str.blank?` and `str.empty?`)

Comment: nil || nil, so not useful?

Comment: Well, rewrite it simple, should make it easier to see that it's the same as the first form: `name || fallback if name == ""`; if `name = ""` then `"" | fallback` -> ?

Comment: The ternary conditional is appropriate in this case (I *rarely* find the post-if form useful outside from nasty side-effects like raising exceptions). However, `if` can also be used as an expression; `if name.blank?; email else name end` (it looks better when put on multiple lines :D). For "trickier methods", see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4817266/if-string-is-empty-then-return-some-default-value - but keep it simple :)

Comment: ok, so it's late but I think the || was trying to compare two string values

Comment: Exactly. There is *no* false-y string in Ruby so `x || y`, where `x` is a string, *always* evaluates to `x`.

Comment: Ok, i've seen the || used like comparing an object (and if object doesn't exist) object || variable... now it makes so much more sense. thank you

Comment: `x || y` evaluates to `y` if and only if `x` is `false`, or `nil` - not so much with `""` or any other value

Comment: `0 || 1 # => 0` Zero is not falsy.

Answer (score 3):

In Ruby, only `nil` and `false` count as falsy. An empty string is not falsy, so it satisfies the condition, and the `||` and after is not evaluated.

On the other hand, `blank?` returns `true` for an empty string. That is the difference between the two examples.

Answer (score 1):

As others have already pointed out, an empty string is true-ish in Ruby, that explains why you need that extra `blank?`. That said, note that active_support is eager to ease the pain, [`Object#presence`](http://apidock.com/rails/Object/presence):

```
<%= current_user.profile.name.presence || current_user.email %>
```

Answer (score 0):

debug on `current_user.profile.name` is an empty string 
means the **following condition**

`if current_user.profile.name.blank?` == **false**

this implies

code

`current_user.profile.name || current_user.email`

will not be executed ,hence the result

Comment: I've tried .empty? and also == "" they all seem to return the same results

Answer (score -2):

The line below:

```
<%= current_user.profile.name || current_user.email if current_user.profile.name.blank? %>
```

Interpreter checks Part 1:

```
<%=  current_user.profile.name ||
```

Part 2:

```
current_user.email if current_user.profile.name.blank? %>
```

Then OR statements gets dilemma , and gives an error. Second Parameter (current_user.email if current_user.profile.name.blank?) is available or not...

Its as per my understanding... Hope you get it.

Comment: wrong you are. right part (`if` condition) is evaluated first, and only if `if` condition evaluates to true => then left part evaluates